# How does ThreadLocalRandom results in less Contention?

Tags: java

Was going through Java 7 new features and found this new class added:

> For concurrent access, using ThreadLocalRandom instead of
>   Math.random() results in less contention and, ultimately, better
>   performance.

Was researcing how this is implemented resulting in less Contention and better performance.

Comment: `Math.random()` is `synchronized`. The source code is available in your JDK installation.

Comment: Totally guessing, but I bet that `Math.random()` has to synchronize to make sure two threads don't get the same random number.  `ThreadLocalRandom`, as its name suggests, doesn't have to synchronize.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - `Math.random()` is not `synchronized` but `randomNumberGenerator` intialization method `initRNG` is `synchronized`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effectively, the difference between the two is synchronization. `Math#random()` may be called by multiple threads simultaneously thus having to synchronize, while `ThreadLocalRandom` is an unsynchronized version of `Random` that is thread bound meaning each thread gets its own (faster) allocation.

If you take a closer look at the implementation, you will find out that `Math#random()` uses a single instance of `java.util.Random` to generate random numbers, where `ThreadLocalRandom` allocates an instance per thread thus eliminating contention in that sense.

`ThreadLocalRandom` achieves *concurrency* where `Math#random()` achieves *synchronization*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, well just wondering one more thing, now if we have RandomNumberGenerator per thread, what difference it will make in pseudo random number generation ??

Comment: @SachinThapa As far as I understand, both methods provide randomness of an equal measure.

Answer (score 0):

From java DOCS:

`ThreadLocalRandom` is a random number generator isolated to the current thread. Like the global `java.util.Random` generator used by the `java.lang.Math` class, a `ThreadLocalRandom` is initialized with an internally generated `seed` that may not otherwise be modified. When applicable, use of `ThreadLocalRandom` rather than shared `Random` objects in concurrent programs will typically encounter much less overhead and contention.

`ThreadLocalRandom` achieves concurrency from `ThreadLocal` usage:

```
    private static final ThreadLocal<ThreadLocalRandom> localRandom =
             new ThreadLocal<ThreadLocalRandom>() {
                 protected ThreadLocalRandom initialValue() {
                     return new ThreadLocalRandom();               
             }
   };
```

On the other hand `Math.random()` uses `synchronize` which restricts parallelism. from doc:

> This method is properly synchronized to allow correct use by more than
>   one thread.

Here is the code:

```
public static double random() {
    if (randomNumberGenerator == null) initRNG();
    return randomNumberGenerator.nextDouble();
}
```

And here is `synchronized` `initRNG()`:

```
private static synchronized void initRNG() {
         if (randomNumberGenerator == null)
             randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
     }
```

Comment: `initRNG()` is only going to be called once throughout the entire life of the JVM. What you are looking for is a little harder to explain :)

Comment: this also add to the cost for the first time even.

Comment: Thanks for your response, so what difference it will make having a RandomNumberGenerator per thread in terms of "How random the number is  ??"