# Getting familiar with Threads in Java: Why does this program's runtime increase with increasing number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, random

**Situation**

I am trying to get familiar with threads in Java. For that reason I modified a program listing I found in a book. What is does is pretty simple:

1. It creates a `boolean[]`-array with 100.000.000 elements.
2. It randomly fills that array's elements with `true` or `false` using `NUMBER_OF_SERVERS` threads.
3. Finally it scans that array with `NUMBER_OF_SERVERS` threads and counts how many entries are set to `true`

For further details, please see the code below on the bottom of this post.

**Problem**

When I run the code with different number of threads and measure the runtime, I get a very strange result; or at least a behaviour that I do not understand: The BuildService-Thread consumes MORE runtime when I use MORE threads. When building the entire array (based on random `true`distribution) in just one thread that takes about 10 seconds. Next, when I use four threads I would expect the runtime to decrease. However, I get a time consumption of about 17 seconds.

My ScanService works as expected: Time consumption decreases with more threads.

Please see the following chart for details:

[image: Thread-Runtime with random <code>true</code>-distribution]

However, if change one line in my code and replace the `if ((int) ((Math.random() * 2d)) == 0)`-statement (for random `true`-distribution) with `if (i % 2 == 0)` (thus, every second item will be true) I get a behaviour I would expect:

[image: Thread-Runtime with even <code>true</code>-distribution]

**Questions**

So, my questions are:

1. Why do MORE threads lead to a LONGER runtime when using Math.random() function?
2. Vice versa, why does the runtime DECREASE when using only ONE thread using the exact same function?
3. What "general rules" can be derived from this behaviour when it comes down to dealing with threads?

**Background info**

The code was run on an Intel core i3.

**Code**

```
public class AsynchService
{
    private static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 100000000; //100.000.000
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_SERVERS = 16;
    private static final int HOW_MANY = ARRAY_SIZE / NUMBER_OF_SERVERS;

    //build array asynch
    public static boolean[] buildArrayAsynch()
    {
        //build array with NUMBER_OF_SERVERS-Threads
        boolean[] array = new boolean[ARRAY_SIZE];
        Thread[] buildServerThread = new Thread[NUMBER_OF_SERVERS];

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SERVERS; i++)
        {
            int start = i * HOW_MANY;
            int end = (i != NUMBER_OF_SERVERS - 1) ? (i + 1) * HOW_MANY - 1 : ARRAY_SIZE - 1;

            buildServerThread[i] = new BuildService(array, i, start, end);
        }

        //synchronize and wait for result
        int expectedResult = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SERVERS; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                buildServerThread[i].join();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

            expectedResult += ((BuildService) buildServerThread[i]).getExpectedResult();
        }

        System.out.println("\nNumber of \"true\"s ==> Expected result: " + expectedResult);
        System.out.println("Build duration: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " ms\n");

        return array;
    }

    //scan array asynch
    public static int scanArrayAsynch(boolean[] array)
    {
        //create services and server-threads
        Thread[] serverThread = new Thread[NUMBER_OF_SERVERS];

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SERVERS; i++)
        {
            int start = i * HOW_MANY;
            int end = (i != NUMBER_OF_SERVERS - 1) ? (i + 1) * HOW_MANY - 1 : ARRAY_SIZE - 1;

            serverThread[i] = new ScanService(array, i, start, end);
        }

        //synchronize with servers, wait for server end
        int result = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SERVERS; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                serverThread[i].join();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex) {}

            result += ((ScanService) serverThread[i]).getResult();
        }

        System.out.println("Search duration: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " ms");
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //build array
        boolean[] array = buildArrayAsynch();

        //scan array
        int result = scanArrayAsynch(array);

        //display result
        System.out.println("\nResult: " + result);

    }
}

class BuildService extends Thread
{
    private boolean[] array;
    private int start;
    private int end;
    private int expectedResult = 0;

    public BuildService(boolean[] array, int serviceId, int start, int end)
    {
        this.array = array;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;

        this.setName("BuildService " + serviceId);

        this.start();
    }

    public int getExpectedResult()
    {
        return expectedResult;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        if (start < 0 || end >= array.length) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        System.out.println(getName() + ": StartIndex = " + start + "; EndIndex = " + end);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            //if (i % 2 == 0)
            if ((int) ((Math.random() * 2d)) == 0)
            {
                array[i] = true;
                expectedResult++;
            }
            else
            {
                array[i] = false;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(getName() + " finished! \"true\" elements: " + expectedResult + "; duration = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms");
    }
}

class ScanService extends Thread
{
    private boolean[] array;
    private int serviceId;
    private int start;
    private int end;
    private int result = 0;

    public ScanService(boolean[] array, int serviceId, int start, int end)
    {
        this.array = array;
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;

        this.start();
    }

    public int getResult()
    {
        return result;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        if (start < 0 || end >= array.length) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        System.out.println("Server " + serviceId + ": StartIndex = " + start + "; EndIndex = " + end);

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            if (array[i]) result++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The devil is in the details. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) of `Math.random()` has the answer:

> This method is properly synchronized to allow correct use by more than one thread. However, if many threads need to generate pseudorandom numbers at a great rate, it may reduce contention for each thread to have its own pseudorandom-number generator.

To get around this issue, try creating an instance of `java.util.Random` for each instance of your BuildService class, and use that instead of `Math.random()`. A benefit of using `java.util.Random` is also that you don't have to do unnecessary double-int-arithmetic, but can simply use the `nextBoolean()` method.

Comment: Thanks for this great response! That helped a lot!!! I'll post the evaluation and my edited code below. However, there is one folow up question now: Why is the code with just one thread FASTER than the code with multiple threads, all using one synchronized method? Wouldn't you expect the code to run pretty much at a constant speed, when multiple threads have to wait for ONE synchronized method to become unlocked?

Comment: As you can see from your plotted data, both BuildService and ScanService converge around constants when the number of threads grows larger. The offset for BuildService is the overhead that thread synchronization imposes on the program. The lesson to be learnt here is that sometimes, threading is only really beneficial if the individual threads work mostly in isolation, and only rarely use shared resources. In this case, each thread uses a shared resource in every iteration of a tight, long loop, so the results are perfectly reasonable, all things considered.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. I'd give you a second "answer-checkmark" if I could!

Comment: One is plenty! I could have added that extra information in the actual answer. I'll leave it as a comment as a "bonus goodie" for the ones who are interested enough to dig through the comments, muahaha!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably seeing the effect of thread contention in `Math.random()`. Java 7 has the [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501465/how-does-threadlocalrandom-results-in-less-contention) feature to avoid just this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code seems to be using 16 number of threads and each thread is using the Join method as in here

serverThread[i].join();

which seems to not use the full potential of threads.

when using the join you are actually saying the thread to wait till the other thread completes not running the threads in parallel.

you might want to use start method instead of join method.

Try running the changed code and post your analysis on time line.

Good luck learning

Comment: Read all of the code. The `BuildService` and `ScanService` classes extend `Thread` and start themselves upon creation. These created threads are the ones that are joined in the secondary loops, which is necessary when he wants to wait for all of them to finish.

Comment: Agree. Can you also comment on these concerns. What is the effect on the unsynchronized method calls on Math.random() since as per his code multiple threads are never going to access them parallel as they are waiting on each other using join.

Comment: Again, the worker threads are not waiting on each other. The main thread waits on the worker threads, which all run in parallel. When calling `join()` on a `Thread` instance, the caller waits on the callee. The main thread (caller) calls `join()` on the worker threads (callee), thus the calls to `Math.random()` are parallel. The contention (and thus the slowdown) happens because the method is, in fact, synchronized.

Comment: Andreas is right, I think. The join()-methods are used to make the main-Thread wait for the Service-Threads to finish. Thus your statement "each thread is using the Join method" seems not be right. It's the main-Thread calling the method on all the Thread-Objects it is waiting for.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Andreas Troelsen's answer into account I came up with the code shown below leading to the following runtimes.

[image: runtimes utilizing objects of java.util.Random]

Compared to what happened before, this solution now meets my expectations much better!

```
import java.util.Random;

class BuildService extends Thread
{
    private boolean[] array;
    private int start;
    private int end;
    private int expectedResult = 0;
    private Random random = new Random();

    public BuildService(boolean[] array, int serviceId, int start, int end)
    {
        this.array = array;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;

        this.setName("BuildService " + serviceId);

        this.start();
    }

    public int getExpectedResult()
    {
        return expectedResult;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        if (start < 0 || end >= array.length) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        System.out.println(getName() + ": StartIndex = " + start + "; EndIndex = " + end);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            array[i] = random.nextBoolean();
            if (array[i]) expectedResult++;
        }

        System.out.println(getName() + " finished! \"true\" elements: " + expectedResult + "; duration = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms");
    }
}
```